# ValueError: Penalty term must be positive

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, valueerror

When I'm fit my model using logistic regression showing me a value error like ValueError: Penalty term must be positive.

```
C=[1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1e0, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4]
for i in C[-9:]:
    logisticl2 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',C=C)
    logisticl2.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    probs = logisticl2.predict_proba(X_test)
```

getting error:

> ValueError: Penalty term must be positive; got (C=[0.0001, 0.001,
>   0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0, 10000.0])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking more closely, you'll realize that you are running a loop in which nothing changes in your code - it is always `C=C`, irrespectively of the current value of your `i`. And you get an expected error, since `C` must be a float, and not a list ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)).

If, as I suspect, you are trying to run your logistic regression classifier for all the values in your `C` list, here is how you should modify your code:

```
C=[1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1e0, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4]
for i in C:                                             # 1st change
    logisticl2 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',C=i)   # 2nd change
    logisticl2.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    probs = logisticl2.predict_proba(X_test)
```