# How to fix "penalty term should be positive" in a logistic regression using Python Sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a logistic regression using Python and looping through several C's.
However, I keep getting the error ***ValueError: Penalty term must be positive; got (C=0.1)***. Which is very odd to me, since 0.1 is positive. I think the error is not exactly on the C value, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried to look at this question [ValueError: Penalty term must be positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423560/valueerror-penalty-term-must-be-positive) but I couldn't understand how to fix my problem.

And I'm very confused because when trying to plot the decision boundaries the code works.

Let's look at what I'm talking about. The following code works:

```
for this_C, subplot in zip([0.1, 1, 100], subaxes):
    clf = LogisticRegression(C=this_C).fit(X_train, y_train)
    print('Accuracy of Logistic regression classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
          .format(clf.score(X_train, y_train)))
    print('Accuracy of Logistic regression classifier on test set: {:.2f}'
          .format(clf.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

However, the code below doesn't work and I get the error mention

```
for this_C in zip([0.1, 1, 100]):
    clf = LogisticRegression(C=this_C).fit(X_train, y_train)
    print('Accuracy of Logistic regression classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
          .format(clf.score(X_train, y_train)))
    print('Accuracy of Logistic regression classifier on test set: {:.2f}'
          .format(clf.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

What is wrong with this second code? Why am I getting the error ***ValueError: Penalty term must be positive; got (C=0.1)***

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error lies in the loop in the second version.

Looking at the source-code of where it throws the error you're experiencing we see this:

```
if not isinstance(self.C, numbers.Number) or self.C < 0:
    raise ValueError("Penalty term must be positive; got (C=%r)"
        % self.C)
```

This says basically that if `self.C` is not either a `numbers.Number`-object or is not a positive integer, then we get this error.

If we look at what the second loop outputs, then we can understand better why the above line of code gives the error

```
>>> for this_C in zip([0.1, 1, 100]):
...     print(this_C)
...     print(type(this_C))
...
(0.1,)
<class 'tuple'>
(1,)
<class 'tuple'>
(100,)
<class 'tuple'>
```

So, the error is because it's given a `tuple`-object instead of a `numbers.Number`-object.